# On the fly Stream and transcode video with Django

Tags: django, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a model that uses "models.FileField()", which I then display back to the user so they may click the link and have a file rendered in their browser. The user can upload various types of files.

Problem is, I'd like to handle large avi's differently, and have the file stream to the user.

The requirement I have is to simply stream/transcode video files from the media_root dir to an end user's browser, preferably in a mac friendly format. It would be for a couple users at most.

I've search and stumbled upon a few projects:

https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-video

https://github.com/rugginoso/django-transcodeandstream

As I am I a relatively newbie when it comes to django, I'm not sure how to incorporate their code into my proj.

Any thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Amazon Elastic Transcoder](http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/). It is a media transcoding in the cloud. It is designed to be a highly scalable, easy to use and a cost effective way for developers and businesses to convert (or “transcode”) media files from their source format into versions that will playback on devices like smartphones, tablets and PCs.

Or else you can check [Webfaction](http://blog.webfaction.com/2012/11/video-and-image-processing-on-webfaction-servers/), they have Video and image processing on their servers which you can use.

If you will use any of those, you can ask them about the installing process and how to integrate it in your project.

And one more thing, if you want to play the video on the browser, you will need a video player like [jwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com).

Hope this will help you get started! Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was thinking about running a celery task to encode the video into h264 with ffmpeg and use the html5 video tag. I know that's not scalable nor doesnt provide streaming capabilities. At this point I have yet to determine how big the movie files will be, I'm waiting on the requirements, so no telling how bad the buffering would be with this method.